How to get and display country name as 2 letters rather than full country name
I am trying to implement the Country Codes in my app for Phone Auth Login.  This is a SwiftUI app using iOS 17 and below is the code i am using to implement this but it is printing out the full Country Name rather than the 2 letters of the country as listed at Country Codes.
I was able to find some information at a previous post by another user:
Getting country name from country code but this just displayed the Country in full name and not in the 2-letter format.
Below is the Code acquired:

Getting Country Code:

func getCountryCode() -> String {
        let regionCode = Locale.current.region?.identifier ?? ""
        return countries[regionCode] ?? ""
    }


Getting Country Name:

func countryName(countryCode: String) -> String? {
    let current = Locale(identifier: Locale.current.identifier)
    return current.localizedString(forRegionCode: countryCode)
}


Implementing code in my LoginView:

HStack {
    // displays CountryName: full NOT 2-letter identifier
    Text("\(loginData.countryName(countryCode: regionCode) ?? "")")
    
    // displays CountryCode
    Text("+ \(loginData.getCountryCode())")
}
                            

When i display the above in my app, this is how it is displayed:
United States  +1

How I need it displayed:
US +1


What is countries in the first code snippet? You don't need that. If I understand correctly, directly returning regionCode should be what you want. uppercased() if you want.

That is to display the countries and codes in a modal

This question is similar to: How to get country code using NSLocale in Swift 3. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

to get the country codes, you could try this approach, for example with country code in a HStack.
Example code:
struct ContentView: View {
    let countryCodes = Locale.Region.isoRegions.compactMap{$0.identifier}
    
    var body: some View {
        List(countryCodes, id: \.self) { code in
            HStack {
                Text(code)
                Text(" + ....")
            }
        }
    }
}

EDIT-1:
a more principled code version:
struct Country: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var code: String
    // others, eg telephone code
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var countries: [Country] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        List(countries) { country in
            HStack {
                Text(country.code)
                Text(" + ....")
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            Locale.Region.isoRegions.compactMap{$0.identifier}.forEach{ code in
                if let name = Locale(identifier: code).localizedString(forRegionCode: code) {
                    countries.append(Country(name: name, code: code))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

